# How to move a file that starts with the same X characters as another file in the same Directory, and move the lightest one

Tags: python, operating-system

As the title says , in a folder with multiple PDF files i have to move the ones that start with the same 13 characters ( considered as doubles)(One of the doubles not all of them) to a folder named 'doubles' in the same original folder.
The PDF files are already sorted but i would love to get a line to sort them by name first.
Here's my attempt:

```
import os
import shutil

os.chdir('Path of the folder') 
# replace '\' by '/' 

for file in os.listdir()
  if file == 'doubles' :
    continue
#to skip the folder for the doubles
  if file.startswith(point to the next file[0-12]) :
    Shutil.move(file.path,'doubles path')
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collections package to find duplicates. Then get the index of any of those files and move it:

```
import os
import shutil
import collections

path = "yourPath"
pathDouble = os.path.join(path, 'double')

origFiles = os.listdir(path)
cutFiles = [file[:13] for file in os.listdir(path)]
numbers = collections.Counter(cutFiles)

if not os.path.exists(pathDouble):
    os.makedirs(pathDouble)

for double, doubleCount in reversed(numbers.items()):
    if doubleCount == 1:
        break
    else:
        idx = cutFiles(double)
        shutil.move(os.path.join(path, origFiles[idx]), os.path.join(pathDouble, origFiles[idx]))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: My bad, it seems that i'm the one who made a mistake(Sorry english is not my first language), only one of the PDF file need to be transported to the doubles folder(Preferably the one we're pointing at the for loop).
In this case what should i change please

Comment: Here you go, let me know, if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another try, this time it works better :) (as far as the tests that i did go :) )

```
import os
import shutil
import collections
import pathlib



paths='Path here'
origFile=os.listdir(paths)
cutFiles=[file[0:3] for file in origFile]
c=0


for path in pathlib.Path(paths).iterdir():
    if path.is_file():
        c+= 1

#to count how many files in the folder for a loop 

for i in range (0,c+1) :
 #+1 for the double folder , the system is only counting files 
    if(cutFiles[i]==cutFiles[i+1]) :
        shutil.move(os.path.join(paths,origFile[i]),'double folder path')
```